# How to log in programmatically in Vista +

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winlogon, credential-providers

I am wondering how exactly to programmatically login to another user account in Windows since Vista removed GINA. I have read that creating a credential provider is the replacement although I have yet to see an example of a credential provider logging in or loading the windows files like GINA did. I have seen third party terminal servers do this before. I want to be able to log another user in and load windows files while still logged into the original account. How is this done?

Comment: Do you want to run a program under his credentials or open another interactive session? If it's the session, why do you want it?

Comment: Open in a new interactive session. I am working on a remote desktop protocol like RDP.